# SwiftUI removing Firebase remove observer error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I have the following code:

Here is where I init the database ref and the handle

```
private let gameResult = Database.database().reference().child("GameResults")
//
private var gameStatusRefHandle: DatabaseHandle!
```

This is the function where I set the handle

```
func getPlayerStatus(gameId: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

    self.gameStatusRefHandle = self.gameResult.child(gameId).child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

        completion(snapshot.value as! Bool)
        
    }
    
}
```

and this is where I remove it:

```
func removeObserverHandle(gameId: String) {

    self.gameResult.child(gameId).child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).removeObserver(withHandle: self.gameStatusRefHandle)

}
```

The above code is all in a class:

```
class GameStore: ObservableObject {

    private let gameResult = Database.database().reference().child("GameResults")
    //
    private var gameStatusRefHandle: DatabaseHandle!


    func getPlayerStatus(gameId: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {

        self.gameStatusRefHandle = self.gameResult.child(gameId).child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in

            completion(snapshot.value as! Bool)
        
        }

    }

    func removeObserverHandle(gameId: String) {
    
        self.gameResult.child(gameId).child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).removeObserver(withHandle: self.gameStatusRefHandle)

    }

}
```

the setting of the handle and the removal are done in the SwiftUI view on the `OnAppear` and `onDisappear`

The above works when user navigates to the view and the `onAppear` function fires. When the user goes back and the `onDisappear` function fires I get the following error:

`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value 2021-05-20 21:03:26.480564-0400 [33352:1962213] GameStore.swift:316: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Not sure why that is since as you can see I am setting the handle in the `getPlayerStatus` function

Comment: Seems like you have a few potential places for crashes since you're using `!` quite a bit (it's dangerous to do this *most* of the time). You say you're doing this in `onAppear`/`onDisappear`, but `gameStatusRefHandle` isn't marked as `@State` -- does that mean it's stored in an `ObservableObject`?

Comment: @jnpdx I added the full code and yes the class is in an `ObservableObject`

Comment: What happens if you make `gameStatusRefHandle` an optional?